# Tools to narrow down high resource usage on DigitalOcean droplet running WordPress

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean

I run a digital downloads site with Easy Digital Downloads/WordPress on a DigitalOcean droplet. It has always been fast and snappy on the backend admin dashboard. Nothing new has been added in a year (besides routine updates). Recently though, some tasks (such as waiting for the product editing page to load) is taking between 15-30 seconds. Very unusual. Resource usage has also been spiking.

Is there any tools to better help narrow down the culprit? I've been using a WordPress plugin called Query Monitor and pouring over server logs, but nothing is popping out.

Any guidance would be great, thank you!